# CSS3 transform property not working for responsive navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive, hamburger-menu

I found an existing article about this, but the solution given doesn't work for my project.
I've been trying to create a responsive navbar and have created a hamburger menu for small screens, its supposed to tilt 45deg when the class `.change` is applied however it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="bar change bar1"></div>
            <div class="bar bar2"></div>
            <div class="bar bar3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.navbar .menu-toggle .bar {
    height: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #333;
    color: #333;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.navbar .menu-toggle .bar .change .bar1 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you stacking css tags like that?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Same as yesterday bud, this link is a snippet. there is no specific link requiring it be posted in a stack snippet.

Comment: sorry ill edit it right away

Comment: @Laif Nope...code has to be **IN THE QUESTION** to be of use. It doesn't have to be a Snippet but it still has to be in the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Source for that?

Comment: See the link in my earlier comment. *"Then post the code to reproduce the problem in your question, probably as a live demonstration using Stack Snippets. As some people are more used to them, consider **additionally** providing it on JS Bin and/or jsFiddle. Since these are third party services and may be unavailable at any time, make sure your question can be understood without visiting these websites."* as stated...

Comment: In that link it literally says that JsFiddle is acceptable as long as code is available on site as well, however your wording makes it seem like using such sites is not allowed

Comment: Where do I say it's not allowed...you are misinterpreting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
.navbar .menu-toggle .bar .change .bar1 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

You need to write:

```
.navbar .menu-toggle .bar.change.bar1 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

because the classes `.bar .change .bar1`  are on the same element.

Putting whitespace between the classes mean that the class is not on the same element.